# Iterate over list inside a dictionary but 1 item from every list at a time

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary, collections

I have a dictionary `Dictionary<string, List<string>> MatrixColumns` whose content looks like this:

[image: Dictionary Data Representation]

Now, I want to iterate over MatrixColumns Dictionary in such a way that I first get "condition#1" of [0] of key "OPERATOR_ID" and then "delta#1" of [0] of key "DELTA_ID"
and then again "condition#1" of [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miS8u.png) of key "OPERATOR_ID" and then "delta#1" of [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miS8u.png) of key "DELTA_ID" and so on.

Thing to keep in mind is the count of elements inside MatrixColumns can vary and it's not always 2. pls. guide me, How Can I achieve this?

Comment: If you find yourself creating dictionaries of lists and such, it's probably time to [create a class](https://medium.com/@cancerian0684/what-are-four-basic-principles-of-object-oriented-programming-645af8b43727) to capture the data and expose behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class:

```
public class MatrixColumnDto
    {
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }
        public List<string> ColumnValues { get; set; }
    }
```

Use LINQ as:

```
var MatrixColumnsResult = Enumerable.Range(0, MatrixColumns.Max(list
=> list.ColumnValues.Count))
                             .Select(i => MatrixColumns.Select(list => list.ColumnValues.ElementAtOrDefault(i)).ToList())
                             .ToList();
```